# How can I make my procedurally generated texture follow a curve in Blender?

Tags: blender, texture-mapping, generated

I want to texture a blade in Blender. For this, I use a [generated texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wBKf.jpg) that creates this brushed look. Now I want to change the direction of the brushed metal to follow the direction of the curve (picture from [yellow to red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fdKa.png)). Is this possible?

I tried to use the Mapping node to change the rotation of the texture.

Comment: Ask on the blender site https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: select needed faces, unwrap and then straighten it.
However you might need two uvs, one for that effect, another for damask texture for example

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).